# how to style such component in material UI in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

[image]

I am trying to make such kind of setup using material UI but am unable to do it properly using material UI.

I am not able to add the product add and remove setup below which should be below product name and price as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

If it is vital to use material-ui for positioning your elements and it expected to be responsive for different screen resolutions you could use https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Otherwise, you can just use flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

There is a link to codesandbox for expamle made via MU Grids https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-dvhfy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: i have been using grids, but i am not able to design this

Comment: @SagarChavan added example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-dvhfy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: it's bit different than what I actually wanted, but i'll try to make changes into this. ty.